# Does addEventListener take values which are at the time of registering of eventListener for future execution?

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, addeventlistener, display

```
const showMovies = function (title, url, rating, id) {
  const newMovieElement = document.createElement('li');
  newMovieElement.className = 'movie-element';
  newMovieElement.innerHTML = <div class='movie-elementimage'>
  <img src='${url}' alt='${title}'>
  </div>
  <div class='movie-elementinfo'> 
  <h2>${title} </h2>
  <p> ${rating}/5 Stars</p>
  </div>
  ;

  document.getElementById('movie-list').append(newMovieElement);

  newMovieElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
    newMovieElement.style.display = 'none';
});
};
```

Every time showMovies function is called I create a new LI and store it in const newMovieElement.
Now suppose two times this function is called, then the last created LI would have been stored in const newMovieElement. 
I also add an eventListener on every LI created for deletion of LI. 
Now Suppose I click the first LI, then which LI should disappear because `newMovieElement.style.display = 'none';` at the time of click, newMovieElement stores 2nd LI and thus this will set the `display:none` of the newMovieElement(2nd LI added) and not the first LI ?

The result is that if I am clicking 1st LI, then it is only disappearing(which is indeed required) but technically shouldn't 2nd LI disappear according to code?

Comment: I did not understand very well, but I can tell you that when you select an element by tag, id or classe, the DOM selector select automatically the first element in the array. si if you want to handle multiple elements you could always use `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: No, what you are saying is not at all related to my question!

Comment: No, you are going to be ok.  That is because all local variables used in your event handler is saved as so called "closure".  When you call showMovies second time - it will have own closure with own instances of scoped variables, including the newMovieElement.  I recommend to read this article on the topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @TanmayLodha Sorry again, I really did not understand very well! but I hope someone can help you!

Comment: So, `newMovieElement.style.display = 'none';` this will hide that element which newMovieElement stored at the time of registering eventListener and not the element which is currently stored inside newMovieElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each dynamically created function (e.g. your event handler) get the surrounding scope bound to it, so it has access to those variables (including `newMovieElement`). This is called "lexical scoping" or "closure". And each `newMovieElement` contains another `<li>` element.

Read here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
- https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html

Comment: So, `newMovieElement.style.display = 'none';` this will hide that element which newMovieElement stored at the time of registering eventListener and not the element which is currently stored inside newMovieElement?

Comment: Exactly. Each time `showMovies` runs, a new scope is created. This scope get's `newMovieElement` as a variable, with a fresh `<li>`. When you create your click event listener (a function), then this function has persistent access to the scope where it was created, even later when the `showMovies` - that created it - had terminated already. This is a very helpful concept which works very well with asynchronous code, as it's very easy to pass data known at creation time to the async code in the function (it's just there)

Comment: But for this to work, that variable needs to be defined inside the function which contains addEventListener and not outside of the function?

Comment: Variables defined on the top level (outside of any function) are stored on the global scope. When running in the browser, that's the `window` object. The global scope is created when the JavaScript interpreter starts (when the window loads. The variables there are shared = accessible everywhere.

Comment: Yup, I know this, what am I asking is that if newMovieElement had been declared globally, then this lexical scoping work would not work right i.e then if we will click 1st LI, then also 2nd LI would be deleted.

Comment: If declared globally, you still get a new `<li>` for each call to `showMovies()`. But `newMovieElement` would then always hold only a reference to the last created `<li>`. All  click handlers would hide that last element.

Comment: I have added a delete confirmation modal for deletion of added movies. 
Now does this delete confirmation modal also has its own closure with own instances of scoped variables, including the newMovieElement?

What I mean is that if I click on second movie and then click cancel on the delete confirmation modal(then the event listener for delete/cancel button remains applied on it as I do not remove it). Now if I click on first movie and then click on delete button, then the eventListener of second movie is also getting executed and as a result both the movies are getting deleted.

Comment: @TanmayLodha you should post a new question for this, we need to see the code. You can ping me here with the url to it, if you want